# actualizar div me actualiza pero en texto

Tags: javascript

hola amigos tengo este problema, conseguí este código para actualizar un div cada 3 segundos

```
    <script>
  function sendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "tabla.php",
      success:
        function(Reload_Tabla){
  /* si es success mostramos resultados */
         $('#Reload_Tabla').text(Reload_Tabla);
      },
      complete: function() {
  /* solo una vez que la petición se completa (success o no success)
     pedimos una nueva petición en 3 segundos */
         setTimeout(function(){
           sendRequest();
         }, 3000);
        }
      });
    };

  /* primera petición que echa a andar la maquinaria */
  $(function() {
      sendRequest();
  });
</script>
```

todo funciona bien pero en ves de recargar la pagina lo que haces es que escribe el código html de la pagina, no se si me estoy dando a entender, bueno este es el código de la pagina tabla.php

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id Dato</th>
      <th scope="col">Id Sensor</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Temperatura Ambiente</th>
      <th scope="col">Temperatura Obejetivo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Id_Datos'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Id_Sensor'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Fecha_Datos'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Temp_Datos_A'] ?> °C</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Temp_datos_O'] ?> °C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Y esto es lo que me bota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quiero que me salga esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Hola, por favor no coloques capturas de pantalla del código, coloca el código original para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Es que me dice que hay mucho código y que coloque mas detalles, entonces no me deja publicar

Comment: si te indica que es mucho código entonces debes leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Un buen ejemplo para tu pregunta debe tener el código relevante y una buena descripción de lo que deseas lograr. Por lo que veo el codigo que muestras no es mucho, asi que lo que debes hacer es poner más detalles aceca del problema

Comment: La solución es escribir más detalles, aparte de colocar el código textualmente y no en imágenes. Date cuenta que lo que se suele hacer es tratar de replicar el error que le ocurre al que pregunta, para poder así trastear con su código a fin de encontrar la solución. Si no se puede copipastear pocas personas van a ponerse a transcribir tu código para ayudarte, lo que disminuye tus posibilidades de encontrar una respuesta que te ayude.

Comment: Ok ya le puse el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar .html() en vez de .text()

```
$('#Reload_Tabla').html(Reload_Tabla);
```

Comment: ok funciono, pero ahora por cada registro de la base de datos me colocara una tabla diferente en ves de colocar todos los registros en una sola

Comment: Eso es porque estas devolviendo solo 1 registro. Devuelve todos.

Comment: como podría hacer eso?, lo siento soy muy nuevo en esto

Comment: ¿De donde obtienes los datos?

Comment: Estas metiendo una tabla en cada iteración, tienes que meter unicamente una fila (tr) para cada iteracion

Comment: Me podrías decir como lo hago?

Comment: Ok amigo ya lo resolví muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que cambiar el  `$('#Reload_Tabla').text(Reload_Tabla)` por

```
 $('#Reload_Tabla').html(Reload_Tabla);
```